# Why tan($\theta$)$\leq \mu$ for a a car on an incline

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

My text book says a car can be parked on an incline if only $tan\theta \leq \mu $

Where mu is the coefficient of static friction

Comment: I recommend you draw out the FBD on an incline with the force vectors. You shouldn't need to memorize tan<=theta. I never use it and have never seen anyone talk about it as a rule until now. It naturally arises from solving the problem and you don't even need to think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be derived using a free body diagram (FBD) of the car. In addition to the force of gravity acting on the car (its weight), the external forces are

1. the normal force exerted by the plane of $W$cos $\theta$ where W is the weight.
2. the force acting down the plane of $W$ sin $\theta$
3. the maximum possible static friction force acting up the plane preventing motion down the plane of $\mu_{s}N$=$\mu_{s}$W cos $\theta$

From here you should be able to conclude that, to prevent motion down the plane,

$\mu_{s}\ge$ tan $\theta$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need your car to stay at rest and mathematically speaking F_brakes = F_gravity i.e the forces should be balanced. Now if tan0>=mu the forces become unbalanced and then there's a resultant force R down along the incline and the can will push into motion, which we don't want.

Now I ask you to do one thing to solidify this concept. Do a problem with the same setup and change the value of tan0 > mu and you'll yourself find out that the value increases disturbing the equilibrium.

*Regards*

Comment: "You need your car to stay at rest and mathematically speaking F_brakes = F_gravity i.e the forces should be balanced." This is not correct. The brakes lock the wheels to prevent the wheels from rotating, but it is static friction between the tire of the locked wheel(s) and the incline that keeps the car from sliding down the incline.